# What is the correct method for implementing <mysite.com/some_user> URL routing in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want my site members to get access to other user's profile pages via URL `mysite.com/some_user` instead of `mysite.com/profiles/some_user`, but with every request to another url path, the view function responsible for the user profile page gets executed.

I expect Django to stop looking for any other url path when it finds a matching path, this is my root URL configuration:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('feedstream/', feed_stream)),
    path('<str:username>', view_profile)
]
```

and this is the view responsible for `/some_user`:

```
def view_profile(request,username):

    try:
        member = User.objects.get(username=username)
        member_events = Feed.my_events(member)
        return render(request,'profile.html',{'member_events':member_events})

    except User.DoesNotExist:
        print('No data')
        return HttpResponse('No data')
```

now when I send a request to a different view for example `mysite.com/feedstream` (which is not a user profile page) , despite the page loads correctly the `view_profile()` also gets executed (judging by the `No data` print on server console)

In other words, in Django docs it states :

> "Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL "

and Im asking why should the `view_profile()` be invoked when there is a matching pattern before it.

I could not find any guide online maybe because I don't know the exact keywords for the problem, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. You have view_profile view for `/username`. Now you want what?

Comment: Despite it works Im not sure it is the right way to do it because after another url for example `mysite.com/feedstream` resolves, Django also runs the `view_profile()` which is not an expected behavior

Comment: @heemayl 
"when I send a request to a different view for example `mysite.com/feedstream` (which is not a user profile page) , despite the page loads correctly the `view_profile()` also gets executed (judging by the `No data` print on server console)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured it out, my implementation method seems to be correct. the reason for invoking `view_profile()` was a GET request made by browser for the static file `/favicon.ico` which matches the pattern `path('<str:username>', view_profile)` . 
with every page refresh this request was being sent, no matter which URL Im navigating to and it was driving me crazy.

Im going to stop this automatic request or to find a workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the view `view_profile` will be invoked for any URL path that is a string (unless you have some filtering for specific paths like `<int:someint>` or alike) on the root level e.g. `/foobar`, /spamegg` and so on.

This is a good place for the specific profiles inside another level of path i.e. within a parent e.g.:

```
path('profile/<str:username>/', view_profile)
```

You can have multiple paths under `profile`, you can also define it in some other file and `include` the URL confs:

```
path('profile/', include('profile.urls')
```

and in `profile.urls` you can do:

```
path('<str:username>/', view_profile)
```

which will automatically be resolved to `/profile/<username>/`.

Comment: yes I could do it this way but as I explained I wanted to avoid the parent level, in Django docs states :
" Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL " 
that's why Im asking why should the `view_profile()` be invoked when there is a matching pattern before it

Comment: @ArminHemati Why you don't want this? Unless you have a very specific pattern in your URL (like all ints) you'd not get what you want. Dividing URLs from parent is the best solution to these kind of problem.

Comment: I consider this to be a better UX design, like how twitter or instagram works, you have `twitter.com/heemayl_`  not `twitter.com/profiles/heemayl` .

Comment: @ArminHemati Then you need to provide this at the end, and put all other URLs at the top but remember they can't be generic like you need something as a prefix otherwise all paths will be redirected to them without coming to profiles as all start at root, without any parent.

Comment: thank you for the advice, Im glad I worked it out now and added the answer. django is working as expected and the problem was a request generated by the browser duhh -_- ...